# Cannot turn on includeExceptionDetailInFaults for certain WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF project with two endpoints. One endpoint "EP1" shows detailed exceptions in the WCF Test Client but "EP2" does not and shows an error message saying:

**The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the  configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client**

I am wondering why this is? I have set the web.config in the same way as "EP1" and on the "EP2" web service class I have added:

```
[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
```

I can't imagine what could be different. I have double checked the class name is definitely correct. Here is the section of the web config:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Portal.EP1" behaviorConfiguration="debug"></service>
    <service name="Portal.EP2" behaviorConfiguration="debug"></service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="debug">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
     </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Am I crazy?